# Comapring one row against entire field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of golf results similar to as follows:

```
name           r1    r2    r3    r4    event
Tiger Woods    71    68    67    72    Buick Invitational 2006
Nathan Green   67    70    69    72    Buick Invitational 2006
J.M. Olazabal  74    64    71    69    Buick Invitational 2006
Arjun Atwal    70    67    71    71    Buick Invitational 2006
```

I want to be able to calculate in percetanges how often each player scored better than his opponents on a given day/round.

For example in the above, out of the field of four players shown, Tiger scored lower than only J.M. Olazabal in round 1. 1/3 = 33%.

In round three he scored lowest, so 100%.

Arjun Atwal scored joint highest in r3, beating no-one, so =0%.

And so on...

Basically I want to check each row against every other row where the event field is the same. Any help greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Just to add for clarity the output I am after would look as follows:

```
Tiger Woods    33%    33%    100%   0%     Buick Invitational 2006
Nathan Green   100%   0%     67%    0%     Buick Invitational 2006
J.M. Olazabal  0%     100%   0%     100%   Buick Invitational 2006
Arjun Atwal    67%    67%    0%     67%    Buick Invitational 2006
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Can you show your initial attempt at a solution?

Comment: To be honest I don't even know where to start. I guess the solution might entail using a zillion IIf statements. I'm fairly new to this I'm afraid!

Comment: This sort of thing gets much easier if you normalise your data.

Answer (score 0):

Because I thought it might be fun, here is SQL that will give you the exact results you describe:

```
SELECT t.name, 
Format((Select Count(*) from [Table] where [Table].r1 > T.r1 And [Table].event = t.event)/3,"0%") as r1,
Format((Select Count(*) from [Table] where [Table].r2 > T.r2 And [Table].event = t.event)/3,"0%") as r2, 
Format((Select Count(*) from [Table] where [Table].r3 > T.r3 And [Table].event = t.event)/3, "0%") as r3, 
Format((Select Count(*) from [Table] where [Table].r4 > T.r4 And [Table].event = t.event)/3, "0%") as r4,
event
FROM [Table] as T;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is stored in an MS Access table called Table1, then the below SQL will accomplish this.  You can generalize this to eliminate the assumption that you have 4 competitors, by using count(*)-1 instead of 3.

Paste the following into SQL view of a new query.

```
SELECT T.name, Sum(IIf(T2.r1>T.r1,1,0)*100/3), Sum(IIf(T2.r2>T.r2,1,0)*100/3), Sum(IIf(T2.r3>T.r3,1,0)*100/3), Sum(IIf(T2.r4>T.r4,1,0)*100/3)
FROM Table1 AS T, Table1 AS T2
GROUP BY T.name;
```